# showing the id after adding

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

What I want to do is to get the id just after adding 
here is my service

```
  public int  Insert<T>(T model)
    {
        var consultation = Mapper.Map<T, Consultation>(model);

        consultationRepository.Insert(consultation);
        return consultation.id;  
    }
```

after inserting I'm getting back the Id value in my service , I just want to get that id in my component so I can show it just after the add
here is my component ,

```
onSubmit(): void {

    swal({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, add it!'
    }).then(() => {
        this.model.DossierId = this.DossierId;
        this.model.DoctorId = this.DoctorId;
        this._consultationservice.post(this.model);
    });

}
```

any idea how to do that ? and thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use your method in your controller api

```
public IHttpActionResult AddConsultation(yourModel consultation)
    {

            try
            {
              int i =  consultationServices.Insert(consultation);
                return Ok(i);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return InternalServerError();
            }
    }
```

and for your consultationservice.post(this.model) samething like this :

```
    postconsultation(model: Consultation): Promise<number>
   {       
    return this.http.post("ApiUrl",model).toPromise()
   .then(response => response).catch(this.handleError);
   }
```